# One of my loops not working, can somebody give me a reason why?

Tags: python, word-count

I'm trying to create a word counter in python that prints the longest word, then sorts all words over 5 letters by frequency. The longest word works, and the counter works, I just can't figure out how to make it check only over 5 letters. If I run it, it works, but the words under 5 letters are still there.

Here's the code that I have:

```
print(max(declarationWords,key=len))

for word in declarationWords:
    if len(word) >= 5:
        declarationWords.remove(word) 

print(Counter(declarationWords).most_common())
```

Comment: Don't edit the iterable you are iterating over.  It wrecks the indexing.

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you can find those changes helpful for your code :D

```
Longest_words=[]
print(max(declarationWords,key=len))

for word in declarationWords:
    if len(word) >= 5:
        Longest_words.append(word) 

print(Counter(Longest_words).most_common())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new list which will contain words with your condition (filter) and use it:

```
>>> s = ["abcdf", "asdfasdf", "asdfasdfasdf", "abc"]
>>> new_s = [x for x in s if len(x) >= 5]
>>> new_s
['abcdf', 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdfasdf']
>>>
```

or a bit other approach

```
>>> new_s = filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5, s)
>>> Counter(new_s)
Counter({'abcdf': 1, 'asdfasdf': 1, 'asdfasdfasdf': 1})
```